# Laravel and blade error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I am getting this error

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/yash/website/resources/views/gamesover.blade.php)
```

I have a table users and a table gamesovers and both have their respective models too namely User and Gamesover.

Now in gamesovers table I have a columns of initiator.

When a get request is sent to the view its code in controller  is

```
public function gamesover()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $games = Gamesover::where('initiator', $user->username)->orWhere('acceptor', $user->username)->get();
    return view('gamesover', compact('games','user'));
}
```

And the view

```
@foreach($games as $game)
{{ DB::table('users')->where('username',$game->initiator)->first()->id }}    
@endforeach
```

In the blade syntax written above give me the error

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/yash/website/resources/views/gamesover.blade.php)
```

** There are no errors with database and the identifiers used have no spelling and case mistake

When I try this using the `dd()` function included in laravel, I get no errors. Also when I try the whole process in tinker then too I do not get any error.

EDIT 1: When I replace `$game->initiator` with a username with quotes, I get no errors AND if I change my code in view to

```
@foreach($games as $game)
{{$initiator = 'yash20'}}  // yash20 is a username already in users database
{{ DB::table('users')->where('username','$initiator')->first()->id }}
@endforeach
```

then too I get errors
Please can anybody guide me what is wrong in the blade statement or there is some syntax error.

If you need other details, please type in the comment I will update the question asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you're trying to get ID from the `null`. Or your query doesn't find any user sometimes.

Try to wrap `@foreach`, getting user ID and the query with these conditions:

```
@if(!empty($games))
    @foreach($games as $game)
        @if(!isset($game->initiator))
            {!! $user = DB::table('users')->where('username', $game->initiator)->first() !!}            
            @if(!is_null($user))
                echo $user->id;
            @endif
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Try to remove them step by step and you'll find where is the problem.

Comment: New error :- `htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: Try to use `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}`. If it didn't help, the error is not related to this code and you should look into other part of the Blade view.

Comment: Well error is occuring due to this blade syntax and I knew this by the error `ErrorException in 849c2df06779b7e62731ecd7e75bb8c6ffc9c648.php line 5:
`  and the line 5 in given view is the one that I asked about in the question

Comment: Please post whole blade view and tell me what line is 5th at the moment when you get `htmlentities()` error.

Comment: According to your edit I removed the code step by step and saw that error is still in the `{!! $user = DB::table('users')->where('username', $game->initiator)->first(); !!}` and btw there i no need of `;` in blade

Comment: Are you talking about `htmlentities() expects` or `Trying to get property of non-object` error? Please show me result of `{!! var_dump($game->initiator) !!}` inserted before the query.

Comment: `string(7) "nishu02" ` is one of the results that I am getting while using `{!! var_dump($game->initiator) !!}`

Comment: Please post all results (copy-paste whole `var_dump()` output, it's important).

Comment: `string(7) "nishu02" 
string(5) "nishu" 
string(6) "yash02" 
string(7) "arduino" 
string(7) "arduino" 
string(7) "nishu02" 
string(4) "ciao" 
string(4) "ciao" 
string(9) "yashlotan" 
string(9) "yashlotan" 
string(3) "mon" 
string(3) "mon" 
string(4) "ciao" 
string(5) "abcds" 
string(4) "ciao" 
string(5) "abcds" 
string(7) "arduino" 
string(5) "abcds" 
string(9) "yashlotan" 
string(9) "yashlotan" 
string(5) "abcds" 
string(5) "abcds" 
string(4) "ciao" 
string(4) "ciao" 
string(4) "ciao" 
string(4) "ciao" 
string(4) "ciao" 
string(4) "ciao" 
string(4) "ciao" `All these are in my gamesovers table

Comment: Looks fine, you didn't answer about the error, which one you're getting at `DB::` line?

Comment: Yes `DB::` line give me error, `htmlentities()` error was my mistake which was solved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110001/discussion-between-yash-lotan-and-alexey-mezenin).

Comment: Actually the error is still not solved.But someone suggested to do this in the controller so it will be safe from attacks

Comment: You shouldn't use `htmlentities()` and similar commands in a Laravel, cause it does this for you automatically under the hood.

Comment: Well ok I will not use them anymore but using `{{}}` automatically include it but when you showed me `{!! !!}` which do not use htmlentities I tried using it and was a success thank you